# Burninate [ca2000] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[ca2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ca2000) has 16 questions tagged with it.

Is it really possible to be an expert in that FxCop warning?

Comment: With 16 questions it is very easy to remove these yourself. The tag will automagically disappear when the clean-up script runs and there are no questions tagged with it.

Comment: Maybe he's not sure whether it should be done or not, that's why asking.

Comment: @bluefeet Is that a "yes please, just do it, it's not at all contentious so we don't need to discuss it"? Would that apply to other FxCop errors too?

Comment: Just help him if you can

Answer (score 4):

> Is it really possible to be an expert in that FxCop warning?

*Whoooooooo cares?* "Can there be an expert in this" is a *terrible* test for the validity of a tag - all it tells you is that *you* are not an expert in the topic and can't imagine that someone else could be. Which could reflect either a lack of potential for expertise... or just a poor imagination.

Here's what you should look for when evaluating a tag:

- **Does it represent the content of the posts on which it is applied?** If folks are asking questions about a specific FXCop warning, then this is probably the case.
- **Does it have a clear, unambiguous meaning?** This is where a lot of tags start to see problems, but this one doesn't appear to be suffering from it.
- **Is it so broad that it could be applied to any question?** No, it's pretty much only for questions about that one error.
- **Is it so narrow that it could only be applied to one or two questions, ever?** Again, clearly not the case.

So... why waste your time worrying about this?

Comment: In general, I concurr with your evaluation and the guidelines which brought you there. Still, I think you applied the test for too narrow much too narrow, which coincidently inverts the final result I see here.

Comment: I gotta be honest: I think removing things because they're too narrow is a gigantic waste of time. Come up with criteria that can be applied automatically, and let the system do it. In this case, we have 12 questions - that's more than some libraries and platforms get.

Comment: If a tag fulfills your last criterion, isn't it automatically culled shortly after creation, even though it has that one question? And wouldn't that encourage creating a unique tag for every warning?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags